# Null Pointer Error when Mocking JDBC Template execute method

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock the JDBC Template's execute method to unit test my data insertion class

Line I am trying to mock is

```
it result= jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_INSERT_QUERY, fileName, sqlStartDate, stgTableName, fileFreq, currdate, record);
```

My test class :

```
@Mock
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

JdbcTemplate mockTemplate = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);

Mockito.when(mockTemplate.update(Mockito.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.<Object>any())).thenReturn(1);
```

My stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1521)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:627)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:941)
    at com.swidBP9.staging.processor.FeedItemProcessor.loadInvalidRecordsToDb(FeedItemProcessor.java:80)
    at com.swidBP9.staging.processor.FeedItemProcessor.process(FeedItemProcessor.java:58)
    at com.swidBP9.staging.processor.FeedItemProcessorTest.feedIemProcessTest(FeedItemProcessorTest.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I am getting a Null pointer exception.
Not able to figure out what is the issue. Can any one please help?
Thank you.

Comment: can you add the whole test case to the op?

Comment: I tried to add my whole test class but I get the error "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Looks like you are mocking the wrong overload of update. Also, post entire stack trace If you need more help.

Comment: I have updated the OP with stack trace

Comment: @NikhilNadkar the stack trace shows a series of JdbcTemplate methods. This is not how mocks behave, it looks like you are not injecing mock to FeedItemProcessor in a correct way.

Comment: You're mocking the wrong overload, the mock only has 2 args the prod code 7 those are completely different methods whether or not they share the same names

Comment: I was not injecting the mock correctly. Thats why it was calling JdbcTemplate methods. Once I fixed that it started working. Thank you all for the help.